# Web2py upload filename different in Static to database

Tags: mysql, upload, filenames, web2py

I have an SQLFORM.factory form with a field:
    Field('photo', 'upload', uploadfolder=os.path.join(request.folder,'static/images/students/')),

on successful upload it inserts the filename into the database and saves the image file in static/images/students/
    db.student.insert(..., photo = request.vars.photo, ...)

But when I look in the database the file's name is stored as:
student.photo.9d313a71112989fe.706f7274726169742e706e67.png

But in static/images/students/ it's stored as:
student.photo.a8c742a692b9f60c.706f7274726169742e706e67.png

which means when I try to load the image in another view, using the name stored in the database, the image cannot be found.

Can anyone help me store the DB name the same as the filename in static so I can load the images I've just uploaded?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely storing the file twice -- once in the static folder via the call to `SQLFORM.factory`, and once in the uploads folder (the default upload location) via the call to `db.student.insert`. Each time, the filename includes a unique random component, and the particular filename stored in the database is the one generated by the call to `db.student.insert`, not the one generated by `SQLFORM.factory`.

A better approach would be to use `SQLFORM(db.student)` to generate the form rather than `SQLFORM.factory`, unless you need to add additional fields or combine fields from multiple database tables. If you must use `SQLFORM.factory`, then insert `form.vars.photo` (which will contain the filename generated by `SQLFORM.factory`) rather than `request.vars.photo` (which contains the actual file object and will trigger a new file creation):

```
db.student.insert(..., photo=form.vars.photo)
```

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks again @Anthony. I did need to use SQLFORM.factory because I have a couple of dropdowns in there for which I need the value for the chosen item rather than its contents, if you see what I mean.